# Stack overflow error in sample program for compiling project

Tags: compiler-errors

I'm writting a sample program for testing a compiler for the Tool language. [Here](http://lara.epfl.ch/w/cc16:tool) you can find some documentation for the language. The code of my program is as follows:

```
program CountChange {
 println(new countChangeApp().initCoins().countChange(300));
}

class countChangeApp{
 var array: Int[];

 def initCoins() :countChangeApp = {
  array = new Int[7];
  array[0] = 5;
  array[1] = 10;
  array[2] = 20;
  array[3] = 50;
  array[4] = 100;
  array[5] = 200;
  array[6] = 500;

  return this;
 }

 def countChange(money:Int):Int = {
  return this.computeCountChange(money,array);
 }

 def computeCountChange(money: Int,coins :Int[]): Int = { 
    var answer : Int;
    if (money < 0 || coins.length == 0) answer = 0;
    else if (money == 0) answer = 1;
    else answer = this.computeCountChange(money-coins[0],coins) + this.computeCountChange(money,this.tail(coins));
    return answer;
 }

 def tail(array: Int[]): Int[] = {
  var tail : Int[];
  var i : Int;

  if(0 < array.length){
   tail = new Int[array.length - 1];
   i = 0;
   while(i < array.length - 2){
    tail[i] = array[i+1];
    i = i+1;
   }
  }else{
   tail = new Int[array.length];
  }
  return tail;
     }

}
```

So basically, what the programs that is compute the number of ways you can give change of 300 with coins of size 5,10,20,50,100,200 and 500.

I've also tested thoroughly the tail function that appears at the bottom so that shouldn't be our concern.

The problem is that when I execute it (following [this](http://lara.epfl.ch/w/cc16:tool_reference_compiler) instructions) I get a nasty StackOverflowError of the form:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at countChangeApp.computeCountChange(countchange.tool:29)
```

where the last line is repeated many times. My guess is that maybe I'm reserving too mach memory for the arrays. Anyone sees what the problem may be?

Comment: While this may be in preparation for a compiler construction cause, the question "What's the error in my change-counting function?" is by itself not related to compiler construction in any way, so I've removed the tag.

Comment: @sepp2k thanks for your punctualization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My guess is that maybe I'm reserving too mach memory for the arrays.

Judging from the error message, your language is running on the JVM. The JVM never stores arrays on the stack, so large arrays can't cause a stack overflow.

> ```
> tail = new Int[array.length - 1];
> i = 0;
> while(i < array.length - 2){
>  tail[i] = array[i+1];
>  i = i+1;
> }
> ```

You're creating an array of n-1 elements, but are only writing n-2 elements into it. So the last element will be 0.

In terms of your change-counting logic this means that you have a 0-valued coin. And that means that once you reach that 0-valued coin, when you do `money-coins[0]`, you'll end up with the exact same amound of money, leading to infinite recursion. And barring tail-recursion optimization (which wouldn't apply here anyway as the function's not tail recursive), infinite recursion always leads to a stack overflow.